# Box-Cox transformation

Tags: data-transformation

I'm trying to normalize some of the variables (biological parameters) from my dataset (some are positively, some are negatively skewed). As I was more familiar with, I used log or square root transformation. However, even after performing these transformations, I hadn't succeeded in normalizing all of these variables. Now I have some questions:

1. Is it correct to use a Box-Cox transformation for all the variables?
2. How can I report the Box-Cox transformed data (I need this transformation for performing multiple linear regression and Cox regression)? For example, when using log transformation I used to report the increase in 1 SD for the transformed variable in the Cox analysis
3. Hypothetically, is it correct to use in a linear regression analysis data that are transformed by different methods (log, square root, log of the reflected data)?

Thank you

Comment: By 'normalize' do you mean "transform a variable to appear close to normal"? If so, why would you do that?

Comment: Transform a variable so that it has a normal distribution. So that I can use it (them) in different regression analyses.

Comment: Not even marginal normality is required for regression, as is addressed in many, many threads here. There can be no objection to using different transformations (including none at all) in a project provided that those transformations lead to improved analyses. In regression the most important changes that transformation might make are to improve linearity.

Comment: In statistics, variables are not "parameters", whatever the jargon in your branch of science.

Comment: First of all, thank you for these ascertainments. Second, as I mentioned in my first post, my final objective is to use the transformed variables in a multiple linear and also in a Cox regression. I'm not a statistician, so my reasoning could be wrong. That's why I asked these questions here.

Comment: Searching our site for [regression transform independent variable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+transform+independent+variable) produces many good links.  I chose the first of these as a duplicate, understanding that although it does not address all your questions, it and some of the remaining search hits will cover the bases.